# Brake fluid colour diagnosis

Tags: brakes

This scooter was sitting for about 6 months, last serviced in 2016. Left brake fluid reservoir has this weird colour. Can it be fixed just by replacing the fluid and flushing the system, or could it be something more serious? The right hand brake fluid seems to be ok.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it.

Brake fluid is hygroscopic ie it absorbs water over time and this may be an indication.

Brake fluid should be changed on a time interval or number of kilometers anyway so it won’t hurt to do it early, especially after a period of non-use.

Answer (score 2):

Confirming that brake fluid change fixed the issue.